# Qt MouseMove event not being caught in eventFilter()

Tags: c++, qt

It is simply not working.
I have enabled mousetracking, then installed the event filter, everything is fine, except for MouseMove events.
Any assistance, please?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setMouseTracking(true);
    installEventFilter(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        QMouseEvent *mEvent = (QMouseEvent*)event;
        qDebug() << mEvent->pos();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638420/qmainwindow-not-tracking-mouse-with-setmousetracking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is quite strange, you ask `this` to filter himself

```
installEventFilter(this);
```

I would'nt be surprised if Qt did simply ignore self-filtering events

Try this for detecting mouse move events in the central widget:

```
centralWidget()->installEventFilter(this);
centralWidget()->setMouseTracking(true);
```

Or, for detecting mouse move events in the MainWidget, use `setMouseTracking(true)` on `this` and instead of adding an event filter, reimplement the `mouseMoveEvent()` protected function:

```
//In constructor:
setMouseTracking(true);
```

and

```
void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
{
    //do stuff here

    event->reject(); //To avoid messing QMainWindow mouse behavior
}
```

Comment: QMouseEvent no longer has reject() method, how to do this in Qt >4.8?

Comment: Diana, you have to use the setAccepted(bool)-function.

Comment: @Diana event->ignore() works as in IceFire's answer.

Answer (score 4):

this is another design issue of QT: eventFilter will not receive the event... UNLESS you override mouseMoveEvent and ignore the signal there.

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e) override { e->ignore(); }
```

Now, eventFilter can be used... and this is often desirable because you might have some eventFilter class that you would like to use with multiple widgets.

Answer (score 1):

QMainWindow has centralWidget that is located over MainWindow area.
Try to add to MainWindow constructor this code

```
ui->centralWidget->setMouseTracking(true);
```

Mouse events will come first to MainWindow and then to centralWidget.